# Can't make Dracula theme work on Vim [os: W10]

Tags: windows, vim

So, I followed the instuctions in their [website](https://draculatheme.com/vim), there's a `.vim/pack/themes/start` path with the dracula folder there with everything and I add the three lines to the `_vimrc` (had to open as admin to be able to save changes) file in my `FilesProgram/Vim` folder

after that, two other files appeared, a `._vimrc.un~` and `_vimrc~` and now when I try to open vim it gives the following error

```
Error detected while processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\_vimrc:
line   41:
E919: Directory not found in 'packpath': "pack/*/opt/dracula"
line   43:
E185: Cannot find color scheme 'dracula'
```

Can anybody tell me where Is the mistake and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

We have a cascade of mistakes, here.

The first one was made by the Dracula maintainers, who forgot not everyone uses the same system as them and therefore only provided instructions for "Unix"-like systems and not for Windows (and even those are incorrect anyway).

The second one was made by you, who blindly followed "Unix" instructions on Windows despite the many incompatibilities between those systems.

The third one was also made by you, who edited the system-wide `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\_vimrc` instead of *your* `C:\Users\Edrods\_vimrc`.

Follow these steps to fix your setup:

1. Create `C:\Users\Edrods\vimfiles\`.

   This directory is where all your configuration is supposed to happen. **Don't do anything *Vim-related* anywhere else**.

   Whenever you see `~/.vim/` mentioned in a tutorial or `README.md`, replace it mentally with `C:\Users\Edrods\vimfiles\`.
2. Create `C:\Users\Edrods\vimfiles\vimrc`.

   This is your main configuration file.

   Whenever you see `vimrc`, `.vimrc`, or `_vimrc` mentioned in a tutorial or `README.md`, replace it mentally with `C:\Users\Edrods\vimfiles\vimrc`.
3. Revert any change you may have performed in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\`.

   - Whatever line you have added to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\_vimrc` must be *moved* to `C:\Users\Edrods\vimfiles\vimrc`.
   - Whatever file or directory you may have added to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\` must be *moved* to `C:\Users\Edrods\vimfiles\`.

   The goal is to return `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\` to its pristine state and forget that directory even exists. It is off-limits.
4. Put the `dracula` directory where it belongs:

   ```
   C:\Users\Edrods\vimfiles\pack\themes\start\dracula
   ```
5. Add these lines to your `vimrc` (remember what I said earlier about mentally replacing it with the correct path?) if they are not there already:

   ```
   syntax enable
   colorscheme dracula
   ```
6. (Optional) Tell the maintainers of that colorscheme to fix their installation instructions.

Comment: Hey, maintainer here  if there are problems we’d love to know on GitHub (yes, I admit the Windows thing was an oversight, but you reference something else that I’m not sure about… at any rate, issues for those things would be great).

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I'm not particularly interested in contributing to your project. The error in question is that you tell your users to do `packadd! dracula`, which is useless given your prior instructions.

Comment: Well, if memory serves, you can’t call colorscheme till after the package is loaded, no? Especially because dracula’s colorscheme file relies on an autoloaded file; we ran into issues when we left packadd! out with the file not being in runtimepath properly (in my personal setup, I delay the colorscheme line until a plugin file so that the runtimepath is already set right).

Comment: If your colorscheme relies on autoloaded files, then yes `packadd!` is needed. But I just took a peek at your repo and the only reason why `colors/dracula.vim` depends on `autoload/dracula.vim` is all the `g:dracula#palette.*` variables. Move those definitions to where they belong, `colors/dracula.vim`, and you won't need that silly `autoload/dracula.vim` for `colorscheme dracula`.

Comment: That happened as a [solution](https://github.com/dracula/vim/pull/139) to an [airline problem](https://github.com/dracula/vim/issues/138); I [argued against it at the time](https://github.com/dracula/vim/issues/140#issuecomment-496707448), but we've stuck with it (it was [documented](https://github.com/dracula/vim/pull/142)). Anyways, we'll definitely need to provided better Windows support…